# Swift cannot print to console using the terminator argument

Tags: printing, console, swift2

I am making making a command line application to learn swift and OOP programming. My code works fine in the Xcode debugger (I see the input and output just fine), however when I archive and export my project, I for some reason cannot see the output of the `print` function.

Here is an example of what I mean.

Debugging in Xcode:

```
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 0
Username: User
Password: Pass
User: User sucsessully added to the system
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 1
User
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 0
Username: User2
Password: Pass
User: User2 sucsessully added to the system
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 1
User
User2
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 2
Delete user: User2
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 1
User
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
Option: 3

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Now when I run the archived exported command line application in terminal:

```
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
0
User
Pass
Option: Username: Password: User: User sucsessully added to the system
Welcome to the login system
-----------------------------

Add a user    [0]
List users    [1]
Delete user   [2]
Quit System   [3]
-------------------------------
3
```

As you can see, the program registers my input and sometimes prints.

I have tried to take away the `terminator: ""` away from the `print` function to see if that is the issue and it printed just fine. This seems to be an issue with the terminator argument. I have also tried to replace the `""` to `" "` for the terminator argument and it still doesn't work.

Why is it I cannot output to the console with the `terminator` argument?

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

var running:Bool = true
let loginSystem = LoginSystem()


repeat
{
print("Welcome to the login system")
print("-----------------------------\n")
print("Add a user    [0]")
print("List users    [1]")
print("Delete user   [2]")
print("Quit System   [3]")
print("-------------------------------")
printToConsole("Option: ")
let option = input().intValue

//Add a user
if option == 0
{
    print("Username: ", terminator: " ")
    let username = input()
    print("Password: ", terminator: " ")
    let password = input()
    print("User: \(username) sucsessully added to the system")
    loginSystem.addUser(username, password: password, uid: 0, guid: 0)

//List users
} else if option == 1 {
    let users = loginSystem.getUsers()
    printArray(users)

//Delete user
} else if option == 2 {
    printToConsole("Delete user: ")
    let user = input()
    loginSystem.deleteUser(user)

//Quit
} else if option == 3 {
    running = false
}
clear()
} while running

print("")
```

printArray(theArray: [AnyObject]):

```
func printArray(theArray:[AnyObject])
{
    for item in theArray
    {
        print("\(item)")
    }
}
```

clear()

```
func clear()
{
    let clearCommand = "if [ -n \"$STY\" ]; then clear; fi"
    system(clearCommand)
}
```

input()

```
func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    let strData = NSString(data: inputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return strData.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
}
```

intVal

```
extension String
{
    var intValue:Int
    {
        return Int(self)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
repeat 
{
fflush(stdout)
print("Welcome to the login system")
```